# Docker Apex for local database

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-apex

I want to intigrate Apex into our system.
As part of the testing and developing process, i want to be able to try things locally before doing it in any other DB.

Ive found guides that explain how to do it between 2 docker instances (one with the DB and the other with the Apex) but that doesnt really work for my need.
We have local databases which id like a Docker Apex to connect to (and install).

Is it possible? and if so, how can i do it?

Ive tried taking the Apex imagine from Oracles imagine registry and running different versions of

```
docker run --rm --name apex -v C:/Users/"myuser"/APEX:/opt/oracle/variables --network="host" -p 8181:8181 container-registry.oracle.com/database/ords:latest
```

with a connection string of

```
CONN_STRING=sys/"MyPassword"@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

But it just doesnt work.

Comment: APEX is written entirely in PL/SQL that runs *inside* the database. Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) can be configured as a pass-thru/proxy on an application server, but the entire runtime and application is contained in the target database. Every database you target will need to have APEX installed. You can configure the ORDS proxy to point to multiple databases.

Comment: i want to target my local database in this instance, and use the ORDS through a docker imagine (if i understand you correctly), would that be possible?

Comment: `localhost` is resolved relative to the container and it seems that it's not what you want. To connect from one container to the other you need to specify the same network for them or start them from the same docker-compose file (which [connects them to the same network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)) and then use hostname of the other container as a destination.

Comment: I want to connect from one container into my local machine, I already have it running between 2 containers